# react: why is my button not rendered when the value is set to true and changes each time the component renders?

Tags: reactjs

I am simply trying to disable and enable the renderer on my button:

```
          <td style={{ display: isThirdButtonVisible?  'inline-block' : 'none' }}>
             <Button className='ButtonImportant'  variant="contained" onClick={() => changeCase('openCase')}>wiedereröffnen</Button>
          </td>
```

I am checking the value on a bool which changes from false to true in my state:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
      var x = await GetMessages(props.statePassDown)

      if(props.changeVisibiltyEvent === 2) {
        isThirdButtonVisible = true
      }

      if(props.statePassDown === 0)
      return  

...


  })()
},[props.statePassDown])
```

But even tho I can see in the console that everytime the effect is called and the value from the props.changevisibilityEvent happens to be 2, the variable is set to true but my button is never re-rendered.

I think maybe I have to put something into the brackets at the end where it says `[props.statePassDown]`, but just putting the bool in there did nothing for me.

Can you help me out here?

EDIT WITH MORE CODE:

```
export default function ChatMessages(props) {
let visibility
const [chatRooms, setChatRooms] = React.useState([]);
var timerStarted = false
var chatRoomID


const [isThirdButtonVisible, setIsThirdButtonVisible] = React.useState(false)

React.useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
      var x = await GetMessages(props.statePassDown)

      if(props.changeVisibiltyEvent === 2) {
        setIsThirdButtonVisible(true)
       }

      if(props.statePassDown === 0)
      return  

      setChatRooms(x)
      scrollToBottom()


  })()
},[props.statePassDown])  // here you pass what u want to rerender everytime a variable changes


React.useEffect(()=>{
  chatRoomID = props.statePassDown

  const tid = setInterval(ReloadMessage, 5000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(tid);
  };
},[props.statePassDown])  



    return (//props.changeVisiblityEvent can be either false, 1 or 2 
      <div class='totalView'>
        <div class='topBar'>
          <table>
              <tr>
                
                  <td>
                     <Button className='ButtonImportant'  variant="contained" onClick={() => changeCase('create')}>+</Button>
                  </td>
                  <td style={{ display: props.changeVisibiltyEvent? 'inline-block' : 'none' }}>
                     <Button className='ButtonImportant'   variant="contained" onClick={() => changeCase('closeCase')}>fall abschließen für {props.statePassDown}</Button>
                  </td>
                  <td style={{ display: props.changeVisibiltyEvent? 'none' : 'inline-block' }}>
                     <Button className='ButtonImportant'  variant="contained" onClick={() => changeCase('openCase')}>fall eröffnen für {props.statePassDown}</Button>
                  </td>
                  <td style={{ display: isThirdButtonVisible?  'inline-block' : 'none' }}>
                     <Button className='ButtonImportant'  variant="contained" onClick={() => changeCase('openCase')}>wiedereröffnen</Button>
                  </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Put "props.changeVisibiltyEvent" into the useEffect dependencies array, like this: [props.statePassDown, props.changeVisibiltyEvent]

Comment: That was correct. It was the missing piece :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use useState hook. Take the variable ***isThirdButtonVisible*** in a state and update it's value in the useEffect hook.

```
const [isThirdButtonVisible, setIsThirdButtonVisible] = useState(false):


React.useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
      var x = await GetMessages(props.statePassDown)

      if(props.changeVisibiltyEvent === 2) {
       setIsThirdButtonVisible(true)
      }

      if(props.statePassDown === 0)
      return  

...


  })()
},[props.statePassDown]);
```

Comment: THank you. Unfortunately, this does not change the visiblily of the button. Ill edit the question showing more code